# TreeMap used in SortedSet

Tags: java, collections, sortedset

Why can’t we use other classes like HashSet,HashMap or other classes in place of TreeMap/TreeSet in SortedSet interface?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SortedSetDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        SortedSet s=new HashSet();
        s.add("Akash");
        s.add("Prakash");
        s.add("Bhushan");
        s.add("Chetan");
        System.out.println("SortedSet:");
        Iterator itr=s.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashSet to SortedSet

```
at SortedSetDemo.main(SortedSetDemo.java:10)
```

Comment: First, don't try to run code that doesn't compile. Secondly, a `HashSet` simply *isn't* a `SortedSet` - why would you expect it to work?

Comment: Because hashset don't implement the SortedSet interface. You can either user Treeset or Set interface instead. If you are looking for why Hashset is not in hierachy of SortedSet, you need to consult implementer of those classes.

Comment: Any particular reason, you want to do this ?? assigning hashset object to sortedset interface variable ???

Answer (score 3):

`HashSet` doesn't implement the `SortedSet` interface (a `HashSet` is not sorted). Therefore you can't assigned a `HashSet` instance to the `SortedSet` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using class `SortedSet` you have to use `Set` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Because a `HashSet` is not a `SortedSet`.

In [the list of HashSet's implemented interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), you do not find SortedSet.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot make object of HashSet in refence of SortedSet.Becoz of HashSet exteds AbstractSet not implemeted SortedSet.You can use Set interface in replace of SortedSet.

Set-->AbstractSet-->HashSet-->LinkedHashSet    and
Set-->SortedSet-->TreeSet

SortedSet/SortedMap is interface to sort the data so that for Sorting the data u can directly use TreeSet/TreeMap class becoz these classes directly implements SortedSet/SortedMap